# iOS push notifications and Testflight using ..p8 certificate and apn

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, push, testflight, apn

I'm trying to send Push Notifications to my ios app.  They work fine for the app I download via the App store, but they don't work when I install a beta version using Testflight.  This sort of defeats the purpose, as I want to test out new types of notifications and do the right thing on the app.

I think I'm doing all the right things:

1. Register for notifications on the app and get a device token
2. send the device token to my server
3. send the notification to the device using APNS in node.

The problem is that when I send the notification from the server to an app downloaded from Testflight, I get BadDeviceToken error.  From the App Store, works perfectly.

The code in Node looks something like this:

```js
let util = require('util');
let apn = require('apn');

class PushNotification {
    constructor(production) {
        production = !!production;
        this.apnProvider = new apn.Provider({
            token: {
                key: './apns.p8', // Path to the key p8 file
                keyId: 'xxxxxxxxx', // The Key ID of the p8 file (available at https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/key)
                teamId: 'YYYYYYYY' // The Team ID of your Apple Developer Account (available at https://developer.apple.com/account/#/membership/)
            },
            production: production // Set to true if sending a notification to a production iOS app
        });
        if (production) {
            process.env.NODE_ENV = "production";
        }
    }

    sendNotificationApple(deviceToken, alert, payload, badge) {
        if (deviceToken && (alert || badge)) {
            let note = new apn.Notification();
            note.topic = 'com.xxx.xxx';
            note.expiry = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600 * 24 * 2; // Expires 2 days from now
            if (badge != undefined && badge != -1) {
                note.badge = badge;
            }
            note.alert = alert; 
            if (payload) {
                note.payload = payload;
            }
            this.apnProvider.send(note, deviceToken).then(function (result) {
                console.log(util.inspect(result, false, null));
            });
        }
    }
}
```